How to correctly adding a child node in a Tabulator data tree?
I've indentation problems when adding child nodes to Tabulator data tree. In the followind example you can see output when all child nodes are initially expanded using dataTreeStartExpanded: true
enter image description here
When I use dataTreeStartExpanded: false and add new child nodes programmatically using such a code
var level=0;
data = [{NAME: '1', _children: [{
            NAME: 'child 0', _children: [{
                NAME: 'child 1', _children: [{
                    NAME: 'child 2', _children: [{
                        NAME: 'child 3', _children: [{
                            NAME: 'child 4', _children: [{
                                NAME: 'child 5', _children: []
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]}]    
var tabulOptions = {
    layout: 'fitDataTable',  
    dataTree: true,
    dataTreeStartExpanded: true,
    dataTreeChildIndent: 15,
    data: data,     
    columns: [{title: 'Name', field: 'NAME', width: 300}],
    placeholder:"No Data Available",
};
var tabul = new Tabulator('#_tabul', tabulOptions);
tabul.on('dataTreeRowExpanded', function(row, level) {
    var _childNodes = [{NAME: 'child '+level, _children:[]}]
    row.update({_children:_childNodes});    
    level += 1;
    return;
});

I get this result with indentation problem:
enter image description here
I'm using Tabular version 6.2.
Any help or tips ?
Many thanks
I would expect a result like thisenter image description here
